# How can I build a multiple input audio setup for my KRK Monitors?

Tags: audio, speakers, mixer

I have recently bought KRK Rokit G4 5 and I've paired them with my Eris Sub 8. I'm running this all through a Scarlett Solo 3rd Gen. And I also have a condenser microphone AT2020, which I directly plug into Scarlett Solo.

KRK monitors are connected to Eris Sub 8, which is connected to my Scarlett Solo.

I need to connect my Scarlett Solo with my laptop via that USB. This is fine when I want to playback audio via my Laptop only. I also own a PS5 & a Steam Deck & I want to introduce these 2 into my setup.

There's a separate video switcher that controls the input I want to provide to my display monitor, i.e., either from PS5, Steam Deck or my Laptop.

This switcher connects to my display monitor & I plan to direct the sound out of my monitor to my Scarlett Solo, as my display monitor has a 3.5mm out. I don't want to have to plug different systems every time I switch the device.

I tried to connect a 3.5mm to USB-c to power up my Scarlett Solo, but it didn't power up. I guess 3.5mm output jack wouldn't drive the power & even a direct USB-c connector didn't power it up.

Can anyone please guide me about what can I introduce in my setup to be able to have 3 different input sources that an output audio to my Eris Sub 8 (that to my KRK 5)?  I'd like to be able to plug-in my AT2020 as well to record audio on Laptop (I don't care about microphone input to PS 5 or Steam Deck).

Maybe I need a mixer like this: [Mackie Mix 5](https://mackie.com/en/products/mixers/mix-series/mix5.html)

I'm okay to ditch my Scarlett Solo, as it clearly cannot do what I intend it to do. I'm also fine with connecting AT2020 to Scarlett Solo separately to record. My priority is to be able to route audio from multiple sources, one at a time to my KRK monitors via Eris 8.

Also, I don't want this to be dependent on connecting my Laptop.

I couldn't find proper information about the output coming out of this mixer. I'm not sure if it's a balanced/un-balanced output.

Please guide & sorry if this is a newbie question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to switch easily between multiple sound sources, you need a mixer with a suitable number of inputs. A passive mixer or monitor volume controller with multiple inputs could be appropriate too.

As the manual says, you can connect either balanced or unbalanced signals to the monitors:

[image]

Comment: I need a mixer, got it. Thanks for confirming. I think Mix5 should be sufficient. The only point I can't be sure about is that whether Mix5 has balanced or unbalanced outputs. Rokit can take both, as you just mentioned. Good to have a balanced output.

Comment: @EveMsc Recommendations for specific equipment are off-topic in this site.

Comment: Oh, I see. Gotcha. Thanks for the info here. Appreciate it.